# Complex Variables: Evaluate the Integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Evaluate the integral:

$$\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{e^z}{z^m} \,dz$$

(If possible, try to only use concepts from undergraduate Complex Variables)

Comment: You should show your attempt on the problem.

Comment: I thought maybe using the Cauchy-Integral Formula, but I don't think its in the correct form. @DonAntonio, I'm still a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Laurent series around the only pole of the function:

$$\frac{e^z}{z^m}=\frac1{z^m}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}=\ldots+\frac1{z(m-1)!}+\frac1{m!}+\ldots$$